# Need a little help to modify this VBA code for outlook to forward unread emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I found this VBA code to auto forwarding mails in a specific folder, it’s great but sends all mails every time, I need to send only new mail in that folder… any ideas?
And this is the code i found:

```
Sub SendFolderItemsAsAttachments()

' Run this VBA code while in Outlook

Dim MyFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim notMyItems As Items
Dim notReplyingToMe As MailItem

Dim i As Long

Set MyFolder = Application.Session.Folders("i@mail.c").Folders("test")

Set notMyItems = MyFolder.Items

For i = notMyItems.Count To 1 Step -1

  If TypeOf notMyItems(i) Is MailItem Then

      Set notReplyingToMe = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

      With notReplyingToMe

          .Subject = notMyItems(i).Subject & " - " & _
                     notMyItems(i).SenderName
          .HTMLBody = "Redirecting for your action."
          .Attachments.Add notMyItems(i), olEmbeddeditem
          .To = "i+@mail.m"
          .Send

       End With

       

   End If

Next

Set MyFolder = Nothing
Set notMyItems = Nothing
Set notReplyingToMe = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define this code as the trigger to the
[ItemAdd Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171270(v=office.11)),
which is triggered for all new mail.
Your routine does work on all mail in the folder.

This example is taken from the post
[how to trigger a outlook macro for new mails from shared inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716796/how-to-trigger-a-outlook-macro-for-new-mails-from-shared-inbox)
(and does reply instead of forwarding):

> In ThisOutlookSession
>
> ```
> Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
> ' Tools | Options | Editor tab
> ' Require Variable Declaration
> ' If desperate declare as Variant
>
> Public WithEvents olItems As Items
>
> Private Sub Application_Startup()
>     
>     Set olItems = Session.Folders("xxxx@xxx.com").Folders("Inbox").Items
>     
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
>
>     Dim olReply As MailItem
>  
>     If Item.Class = olMail Then
>         
>         If Len(Item.ConversationIndex) > 44 Then
>             Exit Sub
>         
>         Else
>         
>             Set olReply = Item.reply
>     
>             With olReply
>                 .Body = "Reply to first email."
>                 .Display
>             End With
>         
>         End If
>     
>     End If
>     
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Thanks but, the original routine was great to apply only in one folder… and forwarding that emails…. All I need is to forward only new mail not all mail in the folder.

Comment: What do you mean by "new"? If you mean "unread" then test `If MailItem.UnRead Then`.

Comment: By "new" i mean that mail wasn't forwarded yet

Comment: The property is `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` (DASL name is `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"`); you should be able to access it using [MailItem.PropetyAccessor.GetProperty](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.getproperty). Take a look at a message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) : click IMessage button to see the available MAPI properties. The value is probably `Last_Verb_Reply_Forward`.

Comment: Can you help me to put that condition " unread" in the code... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "read"-status as indicated by harrymc above within your code.

Forward each mail only if it carries the status "unread". Add changing the status from "unread" to "read" into your processing code.

Because of this change of status the next time your code is run, your forwarded email item will appear as "read" so it will excluded from forwarding.

The extent of change for this purpose is one modification in one line and one additionl line of code added.

Before running the code the first time, change the status of each mail within the target folder as you require it.